# Partitioned Observable second stream never reached

Tags: python, reactive-programming, rx-py

I have an Observable handling a web request, where I want to handle a success or failure in separate streams, very similar to [this example](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/partition.html). The main difference between my script and the example is that I do not want merge the streams and then subscribe. I'm using RxPY 1.6.1 with Python 2.7.

```
request = Observable.of(requests.get(self.URL, params=request_params))

request_success, request_failed = request.partition(lambda r: r.status_code == requests.codes.ok)          

request_failed.subscribe(lambda r: print_msg('failure!'))
request_success.subscribe(lambda r: print_msg('success!'))
```

When the request fails, the script prints `failure!` as expected. However, when the response is OK, the script does not print `success!`. Interestingly, when you switch around the order of the subscriptions, `success!` does get printed, while `failure!` is never reached instead.

I figured maybe `request` could not be multicasted, so I tried adding `publish()` to the `request` observable and calling `connect()` after creating the subscriptions. That did not help (so I left it out of my minimal example above).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comparing your code to [the unit tests that RxPy has for the partition operator](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxPY/blob/1.6.1/tests/test_observable/test_partition.py) it looks like the code is almost correct.

You were on the right track, you did need to turn the request Observable into a multicasted observable.

[Here is working code (tested on Repl.it, you will have to convert the list of requests back to the classes/objects you're using in your code)](https://repl.it/@RudolfOlah/Partitioned-Observable):

```
from rx import Observable

def print_msg(message):
  print(message)

class Request(object):
  def __init__(self, status_code):
    self.status_code = status_code

request = Observable.of(
  Request(200),
  Request(404),
  Request(412),
  Request(200),
).publish()

request_success, request_failed = request.partition(lambda r: \
  r.status_code == 200)

request_success.subscribe(lambda r: print_msg('success!'))
request_failed.subscribe(lambda r: print_msg('failure!'))
request.connect()
```

Notice that as soon as the list of requests is turned into an Observable, it's published (`Observable.of(...).publish()`) and only *after* we subscribe on the partitioned observables do we call connect.

The output was:

```
success!
failure!
failure!
success!
```